# Baking bread for fishing bait

Tags: baking, dough

I would like to experiment a little with new fish bait. So I want to make special bread for fishing with specific aromas and tastes [like this bread](http://www.climaxtackle.com/coarse_fishing/mosella_magic_bread.htm).

Bread needs to be elastic and rubbery-spongy, so it will stay on the hook, but should not be crumbly. It will be perfect if it can be dehydrated for later use, but after hydration should retain the same characteristics as a fresh one.

According to my small knowledge in baking bread, I think adding more semolina in the bread flour will increase the percentage of gluten. Is there any easy accessible product I can use to make bread with these characteristics?

Comment: "It will be perfect if can be dehydrate for later use, but after hydration should retain the same characteristics like fresh one." This is impossible. There are types of dehydrated bread such as Knäckebrot, but if you add water to them, they just turn to mush.

Comment: It's an interesting question which I would like to be able to answer @Jane, but maybe it would be better to approach this from a different way. It doesn't need to be bread, or even baked. You want to make fish bait, so what are the characteristics you are looking for in the end result?

Comment: Don't add leavening and don't bake the dough. Just make a stiff flour/water paste and roll it into balls. It will retain its shape and stay on the hook. As a child I used this as bait many times and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

What about [seitan (wheat gluten)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_gluten_(food)) (also available in dried form as e.g. chips)

[image]

or fried (and dried, not shown in the picture) tofu bits

[image]

or [tofu skin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tofu_skin)?

[image]

Pro: All these kinds of food are dryable and rubbery. 
Con: I suspect that you can't make this at home - it would be very time-consuming. (Hm, except the tofu. Buy fresh tofu, slice them into little cubes and fry them. Anthoer con: this might by much more expensive than baking bread :-)

Comment: And you can season the tofu -  even with vanilla flavour (this is somehow odd but it should work. After all it is the fish eating the bait, not you)